# finishactivity not finishing the current activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have activities called ACITIVTYA,ACITIVTYB,ACITIVTYC.

ACITIVTYB and ACITIVTYC extends ACTIVITYA

In ACITIVTYA which is the parent acitivty,i want to  reload the ACTIVITYB. i used the following code

```
finishActivity(1000);
Intent intent = new Intent(ACITIVTYB.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivityForResult(intent,1000);
```

But the  finishActivity(1000); doesnot work, when the same ACTIVITYB is in the screen.

It works from different activity ie when ACTIVITYC is in the screen i can reload the ACTIVITYB. But When ACTIVITYB is in the screen i cannot reload the same ACTIVITYB.

Comment: Why don't you use only `finish` to stop your activity? If you have also started your other activities with `1000` as `requestCode` those will also get killed.

Comment: I don't understand what does extends ACTIVITY A means. Are you means that you have 2 fragment in your activity A?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
getActivity().setResult(350, null);
getActivity().finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to finish your current activty yout must have to remove that from activity stack befire going to next screen fir that you have to use

youractivity.this.finish();